# Installing grub2 in efi-mode in usb flash drive

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, usb

I've two different OS, which one is ubuntu. I'm using a PC, NOT a Mac. I use Chimera bootloader that don't find Ubuntu. So, i'd like to install grub 2 in EFI-mode on flash-drive USB. In this way, i can load Ubuntu only if the usb flash-drive is connected.

I followed this guide https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFIBooting replacing "/dev/sda" in

```
sudo efibootmgr --create --gpt --disk /dev/sda --part 1 --write-signature --label "GRUB2" --loader "\\EFI\\grub\\grub.efi"
```

with the usb-pen directory. Then, i've copied the grub.cfg file that exists in Ubuntu partition.Result? Grub2 loads, but when i select the menu entries, grub2 doesn't find any command, or disks.
How can i fix this problem?

P.S. Here, there are the photo of the error(when i select ubuntu entry in grub2), the usb-drive's contents and the grub.cfg file http://paste.ubuntu.com/7283661/

Comment: Hi guys! Sorry, i wrote the greeting but i don't there isnt'!

Comment: Greeting and signature are auto filtered sometimes. See https://askubuntu.com/help/behavior

Answer (score 2):

I realize I'm a bit late in answering this, but I wanted to do something similar to your setup and ran into the same problem. I finally found a fix and wanted to share it.

It looks like some sort of bug in grub-install. In your USB drive you have this:

```
/EFI/thenameIgavetomygrub/grub.cfg
```

Simply make a copy of the folder `thenameIgavetomygrub` and all of its content (in your case it looks like you called it "grub") into the same EFI folder on the usb drive, and rename that copy as "ubuntu".

Then it should work. At least it did for me.

Answer (score 2):

maybe something need clarify.

### 一. boot menu //seems on Motherboard

[image: boot menu]

#### A. the items in red box

was created by `efibootmgr` (or Or similar tools)

they always here, even if the disk device not exist.
//it's not necessary for boot from device. (just add more entry for boot)

##### 1. parts layout

```
/dev/sda: PTUUID="79be6d7a-0332-4aae-95c6-5798b97db2d5" PTTYPE="gpt"
/dev/sda1: UUID="D18D-CD5C" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI system partition" PARTUUID="3545bf37-ae87-4741-8cdf-fc196833e869"
/dev/sda2: LABEL="u20" UUID="88c19248-455c-4446-b077-3f63b3123c5f" TYPE="ext4" PARTLABEL="Linux filesystem" PARTUUID="d481f035-fbe8-496c-b8be-11ff7b3cf4fe"
```

```
mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/efi/

/mnt/efi/
└── EFI
    └── BOOT
        ├── BOOTX64.CSV
        ├── BOOTX64.EFI
        ├── grub.cfg
        ├── grubx64.efi  // grub2 启动文件
        └── mmx64.efi    // 好像是 诊断模式
```

##### 2. install boot item:

```
efibootmgr -c -w -L 'u20_grubx64' -d /dev/sda -p 1 -l '\EFI\BOOT\grubx64.efi'
```

will got menu item:

```
Boot0007* u20_grubx64   HD(1,GPT,3545bf37-ae87-4741-8cdf-fc196833e869,0x8000,0x80000)/File(\EFI\BOOT\grubx64.efi)
```

---

#### B. the items in green box

was auto displayed when real disk connected.
they will disappear if the disk not connected.

//they can boot grub2 from corresponding disk.

### 二. grub //on disk

A. grub on inner ssd. //ubuntu18
[image: grub on ssd]

B. grub on usb disk. //ubuntu20
[image: grub on usb]

they were installed by `grub-install` from `grub2-common` package.

#### 1. parts layout to create

`gparted` create gpt partition.

- create sda1 part, set part flag: `esp`, set part label `EFI system partition`, format to `fat32`.
- create sda2 part, format `ext4`(as example), //may be installed by linux os, with `/boot` dir inside.

```
sda           8:0    0 465.8G  0 disk 
├─sda1        8:1    0   256M  0 part 
├─sda2        8:2    0    40G  0 part
```

```
blkid /dev/sda*
/dev/sda1: UUID="D18D-CD5C" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI system partition" PARTUUID="3545bf37-ae87-4741-8cdf-fc196833e869"
/dev/sda2: LABEL="u20" UUID="88c19248-455c-4446-b077-3f63b3123c5f" TYPE="ext4" PARTLABEL="Linux filesystem" PARTUUID="d481f035-fbe8-496c-b8be-11ff7b3cf4fe"
```

#### 2. install grub2 efi

mount parts, wait for install

```
sudo mount /dev/sda2 /mnt/p2
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/p2/boot/efi/
```

do install

```
sudo grub-install --target=x86_64-efi --recheck --removable --efi-directory=/mnt/p2/boot/efi/ --boot-directory=/mnt/p2/boot /dev/sda1 
Installing for x86_64-efi platform.
Installation finished. No error reported.
```

this will install grub2 on usb disk `sda`.

those files in sda1 `/`:

```
/mnt/p2/boot/efi/
└── EFI
    └── BOOT
        ├── BOOTX64.CSV
        ├── BOOTX64.EFI
        ├── grub.cfg
        ├── grubx64.efi  // grub2 启动文件
        └── mmx64.efi    // 好像是 诊断模式
```

will show as `二.B` image,
and can be boot from boot menu item `一.B` or `一.A`

kernel in sda2 `/boot`, installed by ubuntu20.

```
/mnt/p2/boot/
├── config-5.8.0-63-generic
├── efi
├── grub
│   ├── fonts
│   ├── gfxblacklist.txt
│   ├── grub.cfg
│   ├── grubenv
│   ├── locale
│   ├── unicode.pf2
│   └── x86_64-efi
├── initrd.img -> initrd.img-5.8.0-63-generic
├── initrd.img-5.8.0-63-generic
├── memtest86+.bin
├── memtest86+.elf
├── memtest86+_multiboot.bin
├── System.map-5.8.0-63-generic
├── vmlinuz -> vmlinuz-5.8.0-63-generic
├── vmlinuz-5.8.0-63-generic
```

and total boot flow:

`efi boot menu item` => `grub2 on sda1` => `kernel on sda2` => `rootfs`

---

### see also:

https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Multiboot_USB_drive
https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/GRUB#Installation_2
https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/EFI_system_partition

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18752/change-the-number-of-the-partition-from-sda1-to-sda2